# Adding Parameters to dataflow Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have a problem, I want to get data from a source but with parameter.
I created new parameter:

[image]

And I try to concat the query:

[image]

This is the error I get:

[image]

Comment: Can you try publish the dataflow and try again? Can you provide your dataflow JSON for better understanding?

Comment: Unfortunately I will not be able to post the Json.. I just tried to concat the query with the parameter, what can cause the issue?

Comment: Is it resulting the same with normal select query with parameter? Can you publish the dataflow and try again?

Comment: when I use a normal select query in other pipelines it works. It doesnt let me publish with this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above error is not because of the dataflow parameter. It's because your query in the string contains new line characters. I tried a query like below without any parameter, but you can see I got same error when I tried to publish or validate the dataflow.

```
concat("select * from student 
where Name='AA'")
```

[image]

[image]

So, to avoid this error, give your query in the `concat()` in a single line like below.

```
concat("select * from student where Name='AA'")
```

[image]